# Why do I need a 'makefile' using a lot of modules or procedures if I don't use '-c' option? (gfortran)

Tags: makefile, compilation, gfortran

I mean is faster to write (bash script) for example:

```
gfortran -Wall -Wextra -o program.out \
rffti.f rffti1.f rfftf.f rfftf1.f radf4.f radf2.f radf3.f radf5.f radfg.f test.f90
```

, than a makefile to do the same.

Comment: You don't need to use a makefile if you don't use the `-c` option.  But any reasonably-sized program will definitely want to use the `-c` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* a Makefile if you don't want to use one. It is customary for languages where you split input into more than one file because `make` takes care of keeping track of what needs to be recompiled; if you share your project with others, letting them say `make` and not care what's in the Makefile is also simple user friendliness, even if it's not strictly required.  And anyway, putting that command in a Makefile is only very marginally more complex and verbose than putting it in a shell script, but leaves much more room for future growth.